# Webform ajax Validation deactivated?

Tags: webforms, forms

I don't understand why the ajax validation functionality was suddenly deactivated on my WebForm. Perhaps is it possible to activate it again?

After fresh webform install all required fields were marked "required" with ajax functionality, if I tried to send unfilled form.

Do you have an idea?